# hibernate entityManagerFactory init throws ExceptionInInitializerError java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring with Hibernate && JPA in a webapp, running on tomcat
On my local computer (Ubuntu 14.04), this works great.
On the server (Ubuntu Server 14.04 - without any GUI, but that shouldn't matter for Hibernate... or?), on webapp startup throws the following exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerEr$
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractFields(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractFields(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractSuper(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractFields(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractFields(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractFields(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractInterfaces(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractSuper(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.toTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.fromMethod(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:650)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.extractMethods(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.makeTypeDescriptor(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.reflite.internal.JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.getType(JavaTypeDescriptorRepositoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.annotations.util.EntityHierarchyBuilder.findHierarchyRootDescriptors(EntityHierarchyBuilder.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.annotations.util.EntityHierarchyBuilder.process(EntityHierarchyBuilder.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.annotations.util.EntityHierarchyBuilder.createEntityHierarchies(EntityHierarchyBuilder.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessor.extractEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessor.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataBuildingProcess.processMappings(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:533)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:156)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.<init>(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit cannot be cast to sun.awt.SunToolkit
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.DataTransferer.getInstance(DataTransferer.java:275)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.<clinit>(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:751)
    ... 132 more
```

The thing I don't understand is why Hibernate needs anything from sun.awt?

My spring-database.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.location}:${database.port}/${database.dbname}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>    

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

And my persistance.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<!-- model objects removed -->
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.location}:${database.port}/${database.dbname}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${database.username}"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${database.password}"/>
</properties>
```

(db config is set from Maven)

used hibernate dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>[4.3.6.Final,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>[4.3.6.Final,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>[4.3.6.Final,)</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT**
Previously used java8u20
Copied the java8u11 install from my local comp, exception changed to:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.<clinit>(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:744)
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: Tried adding a dummy DISPLAY env var to /etc/environments, did not help...

Comment: installing XVFB... no result...

Comment: Installing a GUI fixed it (sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop), but I'm sure there is a better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find a better solution:
In my project, I used hibernate-core-5.0.0-20140702.145403-29.jar (thx to the maven [4.3.6.Final,) version declaration).

A changed it back to 4.3.6.Final, and it solved the problem